# recyclerview onClick getkey from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

How do I get key in kotlin in `RecyclerView` to send it to another activity?
I tried using `getKey()` and `position` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
class RecyclerAdapter (val userlist:ArrayList<RecyClass>,ccc: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var mcontext =ccc

    val  Postdata = java.util.ArrayList<RecyClass>()


    lateinit var  ref:DatabaseReference

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  userlist.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder( holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val user: RecyClass = userlist[position]
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(user.toString())

        holder?.txtviewdesc?.text = user.desc
        Picasso.with(mcontext).load(user.image).into(holder?.imageviewx)
        holder?.setOncustomcilcklistner(object :Custumclicklistner33{
            override fun oncustomOnClickListner(view: View, pos: Int) {
                   }

        })
    }




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
      this.Postdata

         this.mcon
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.layoutrcview,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v,mcon,userlist)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemview: View,ccc2:Context,userlist: ArrayList<RecyClass>): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview), View.OnClickListener{
        var mCustIemClick5: Custumclicklistner33?=null
        var txtviewdesc: TextView
        var mcon =ccc2
        var userdata =userlist
        var imageviewx: ImageView

        init {
             this.userdata
            this.mcon
            txtviewdesc = itemview.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextdesc)
            imageviewx = itemview.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgvw)

            itemview.setOnClickListener(this)
        }


        fun setOncustomcilcklistner(customclick5: Custumclicklistner33){
            this.mCustIemClick5=customclick5
        }

        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            this.mCustIemClick5!!.oncustomOnClickListner(view!!,adapterPosition)
            val pos = adapterPosition
           val ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(pos.toString()).key.toString()
            Toast.makeText(mcon,ref,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            var postDetail = this.userdata[pos]
             val kkk = Intent(this.mcon,ProfileActivity::class.java)
            kkk.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
           this.mcon.startActivity(kkk)
        }
    }
}
```

`fun onclick` takes to next activity but it takes post's `key`. How to get it? 
`getref` and `postiton` is not working in `fun onclick` but it works on `bindviewholder`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PostData[position] to get the object that current position and then a key/field from that object that you can reference.

Comment: postData not workin , but i tried using var postDetail = this.userdata[pos] but it does not give post key but whole data class with all values in it .. how do i retrieve post key from it ??

Comment: What does your postDetail object look like?

Comment: its arraylist of data class named ArrayList<RecyClass> has values of image,description,uid,username

Comment: val key = ref.key[position] , i  tried this but it shows me    error StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=15

Comment: you need to update the list each time the values change and then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: yes when i add data on firebase i put the key in database ,which in return gives me position key

Comment: thank you - can you please accept the response or let me know how I can help further?